How to modify elements of several plugins in an included SDF model?
Suppose that I have an SDF model of a gimbal with three plugins like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sdf version='1.9'>
  <model name="gimbal">

    <!-- Lots of Links and Joints -->

    <plugin filename="gz-sim-joint-position-controller-system" name="gz::sim::systems::JointPositionController">
      <joint_name>servo_yaw</joint_name>
      <sub_topic>servo_yaw</sub_topic>
      <p_gain>1.0</p_gain>
      <i_gain>0.0</i_gain>
      <d_gain>0.03</d_gain>
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="gz-sim-joint-position-controller-system" name="gz::sim::systems::JointPositionController">
      <joint_name>servo_roll</joint_name>
      <sub_topic>servo_roll</sub_topic>
      <p_gain>1.0</p_gain>
      <i_gain>0.0</i_gain>
      <d_gain>0.03</d_gain>
    </plugin>
    <plugin filename="gz-sim-joint-position-controller-system" name="gz::sim::systems::JointPositionController">
      <joint_name>servo_pitch</joint_name>
      <sub_topic>servo_pitch</sub_topic>
      <p_gain>1.0</p_gain>
      <i_gain>0.0</i_gain>
      <d_gain>0.03</d_gain>
    </plugin>
  </model>
</sdf>

I also have another SDF model in which I want to include my gimbal. Normally, I would go like this:
<model name='robot_A_with_gimbal'>
  <include merge='true'>
    <uri>model://robot_A/model.sdf</uri>
  </include>
  <include merge="true">
    <uri>model://gimbal/model.sdf</uri>
    <name>gimbal</name>
    <pose relative_to="base_link">0.175 0.0 0.03        0.0 0.0 0.0</pose>
  </include>
  <joint name="gimbal_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent>base_link</parent>
    <child>gimbal_base_link</child>
  </joint>
</model>

However, there is a requirement where I have to change the plugin sub_topic of the gimbal to servo_0, servo_1, and servo_2 respectively. I cannot just change the subtopic in the SDF of the gimbal because it is used also by other robots, say robot_B and robot_C.
From this link, I know that I can modify the sub_topic element of that particular plugin by specifying its element_id and using action="modify". So, I do it like this:
<model name='robot_A_with_gimbal'>
  <include merge='true'>
    <uri>model://robot_A/model.sdf</uri>
  </include>
  <include merge="true">
    <uri>model://gimbal/model.sdf</uri>
    <name>gimbal</name>
    <pose relative_to="base_link">0.175 0.0 0.03        0.0 0.0 0.0</pose>
    <experimental:params>
      <plugin element_id="gz::sim::systems::JointPositionController" action="modify" filename="gz-sim-joint-position-controller-system" name="gz::sim::systems::JointPositionController">
        <sub_topic>servo_0</sub_topic>
      </plugin>
      <plugin element_id="gz::sim::systems::JointPositionController" action="modify" filename="gz-sim-joint-position-controller-system" name="gz::sim::systems::JointPositionController">
        <sub_topic>servo_1</sub_topic>
      </plugin>
      <plugin element_id="gz::sim::systems::JointPositionController" action="modify" filename="gz-sim-joint-position-controller-system" name="gz::sim::systems::JointPositionController">
        <sub_topic>servo_2</sub_topic>
      </plugin>
    </experimental:params> 
  </include>
  <joint name="gimbal_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent>base_link</parent>
    <child>gimbal_base_link</child>
  </joint>
</model>

But, it changes only the first plugin it found in the gimbal model, i.e. it changes the first plugin sub-topic from servo_yaw to servo_2. I kind of understand why this happens because those three plugins are identical from filename, name, and element_id point of view so the modification happens three times on the first plugin.
Right now, my workaround is to remove those three plugins by using action="remove" in the robot_A_with_gimbal SDF file and add again those three plugins by using action="add". However, I am still wondering: Is it really impossible by using action="modify" to achieve the same result?
